# nightwatch.js how to create a warning

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

I created a little tool that reads my nightwatch test results and styles them, therefore I get a better overview of my tests.

However, to fully test all my features of my tool I need to write a test which will create a `warning`.

All I'm able to get is a `Timeout`. Can someone tell me what I have to do, therewith I get a `warning`.